# change color according to day night time in android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to develop a sample app which can continuously track time and can update app UI with respect to time. i.e. if time is 9:00 am the image is showing morning and after some time interval image is looking different.

may be I am not able to explain my question properly, but I want to achieve something like in this image,[image]

I tried to google it, but not getting any specific method to achieve this, any suggestion would be great help for me.

thanks

Comment: so you have 2 images .. first image displayed in the morning and the other diplsayed at night ?

Comment: you should divide the problem on smaller. what's the simple issue? e.g. i don't know how to get current time, or i don't know how to set background of view

Comment: Get the current time and set the view accordingly

Comment: @Dmitriy I can get current time, but my problem is that how can I update the view/image according to time, means bright image in morning/afternoon and dark image in evening/night

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that may solve your purpose.The concept is simple.Just take the time you want to validate from Calendar class and compare it with the current time and then take an appropriate action.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long noon_start = cal.getTimeInMillis();//3.00

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

long noon_end = cal.getTimeInMillis();//5.30
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();//current time

if(now > noon_start && now < noon_end)
{
    //set your background here
    textView.setText("Good afternoon");
}
else
{
    //set your background here
    textView.setText("Good Evening");
}
```